# Why won't these integers convert to strings? (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7

```
let = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Corresponds letters with certain values
These values are place holders

```
letMap = {'a' : '100', 'b' : '172', 'c' : '936', 'd' : '238', 'e' : '235','f' : '576', 'g' : '111', 'h' : '811', 'i' : '892', 'j' : '401','k' : '777' , 'l' : '209', 'm' : '123', 'n' : '901', 'o' : '378', 'p' : '189', 'q' : '045', 'r' : '888', 's': '700','t' : '381', 'u' : '109', 'v' : '837', 'w' : '378', 'x' : '192', 'y' : '456', 'z' : '521'}

for y in range(0,25):
    ran = random.randint(1,9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)
    letMap[let[myLet]] = ran
    # This will not convert the integers into strings
    str(letMap[let[myLet]])
    myLet += 1
    time.ctime()
    time.sleep( .04 )
    time.ctime()
```

Comment: For starters, try formatting your code properly. The state *clearly* the error that you are experiencing. Also, what's with `random.randint(1,9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)`?

Comment: `myLet` is not assigned in the code we can see. Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

in my little example (see below) it worked fine. Be aware that you should take integers as value in letMap and you did not assigned 'myLet' in your loop. Probably it should by the running index. So just replace 'myLet' to 'y' and kill the line myLet += 1.

Here is little my example:

```
let=['a','b','c']
letMap={'a':100,'b':123,'c':5}
letMap[let[0]]
str(letMap[let[1]])
```

prints:

```
100   (int)
'123' (str)
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers,
Viktor